# Offline installation wifi adapter TP-Link Archer T2U Nano with Realtek RTL8811AU or RT5370 in Debian Linux

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, realtek

I want to get my wifi adapter TP-Link Archer T2U Nano with Realtek RTL8811AU installed in Debian Linux 9.13 with kernel 4.9.88. Alternatively I've got a CAB-wifi-stick with RT5370 chipset.
Unfortuantely the ethernet cable is protected by firewall with root certificate etc. and very limited. I need unprotected internet access and this would be possible via wifi.

All guides I found need internet access to download, compile and build the driver. How can I do that offline?

When I connect the adapter I get:

```
root@ctr-700-456234:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:011e TP-Link
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Alternatively I've got a RT5370 adapter which prints

```
root@ctr-700-456234:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
root@ctr-700-456234:~#
```

ifconfig prints only my eth1 and lo and no wlan0 or similar.

Would it be possible to do a parallel installation of Debian 9.13 on a computer with free internet access, download and build the driver and then transfer it with a USB stick to this PLC? What would you propose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *a computer with free internet access* ... why does the internet access have to be "free"?

Comment: you don't need to do the compilation on the same computer as you load that module.

Comment: @JaromandaX Otherwise I get "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" - errors due to our firewall

Comment: oh, what's that got to do with the internet being free or paid?

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't mean "free of costs" but I meant "free-without-security-restrictions".
Of course our Internet access is never "free of costs" :-)
See "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" to understand what happens by our firewall.